# Numpy FFT issue when shifting data along vertical axis

Tags: python, numpy, fft, trigonometry, amplitude

I want to find the relationship between the y-axis of my data and the vertical axis of my FFT (amplitude). To do this I am testing how the amplitude of my FFT changes when I change the y-axis of my data. For example, I plotted sin(t) from 0 to 2*pi and took the FFT using Numpy's FFT package and got a frequency of approximately 1/(2*pi). I then added 1 to all of my y-values merely to shift my sine function up 1 unit everywhere; however, when I took the FFT, I got something that made no sense. Why is the FFT totally different when I merely shift my sine function upwards? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 10)
y1 = np.sin(t)
y2 = np.sin(t) + 1
plt.plot(t, y2)    # y1 can be used instead
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('height')
plt.show()

fft_power = fft.fft(y2)    # y1 can be used instead
rfft_power = fft.rfft(y2)    # y1 can be used instead

sample_spacing = 0.6981317

frequency = fft.fftfreq(len(fft_power), sample_spacing)
real_frequency = fft.rfftfreq(len(fft_power), sample_spacing)

plt.plot(real_frequency.real, rfft_power.real)
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.ylabel('amplitude')
plt.show()
```

[initial data FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACacK.png)
[shifted data FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GePKl.png)

Comment: Not an answer, but why not use `y1 = np.sin(t)` and `y2 = np.sin(t) + 1`?

Comment: Take this answer with a grain of salt since I haven't worked with fourier transforms for a while now, but I believe that you are seeing effects of aliasing.  If you use my above suggestion for creating `y1` and `y2` and then crank the number of points (say to 1000), you'll end up with a much more similar result.

Comment: You're totally right. I should have changed that and just did. Thanks!

Comment: When you add 1 to `y1`, you are added a term to the signal that has a frequency of 0.  So the Fourier coefficient associated with the 0 frequency changes from 0 to 10.  (The value is 10, not 1, because of the normalization convention used by numpy's FFT functions; see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#normalization.)

Comment: Also, if you are trying to demonstrate the Fourier transform of a single frequency, you'll get a cleaner result if you use, say, `t = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 10, endpoint=False)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will convince you that all is working well:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 10000)
y2 = np.sin(200*t) + 1
```

The 1 adds a very strong peak at 0 frequency. But the sin peak is also there.